# Dataweave Memory Management

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I've been going through the docs on dataweave memory management and came across some confusions related to the configuration of buffer files Link: https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-memory-management

1. `com.mulesoft.dw.memory_pool_size` suggests that by default there are 60 slots in the off-heap memory and `com.mulesoft.dw.max_memory_allocation` governs the size of each slot, if the slot exceeds the default size limit of 1572864 bytes its pushed to a file storage. If thats the case then what is the role of `com.mulesoft.dw.buffersize` doesn't it governs the size of data that should be held in memory and if exceeded push to the file storage, but the same is also done by the previously mentioned 2 properties?
2. The document also states that `dw-buffer-output-${count}.tmp` and `dw-buffer-input-${count}.tmp` have a default size limit of 1572864 bytes after which they are pushed to file storage but, the other property `com.mulesoft.dw.buffersize` that governs the limits shows the default size set to 8192 bytes, isn't it incorrect?
3. Quoting the sentence from the document regarding the property `com.mulesoft.dw.memory_pool_size`
   `Since Mule 4.3.0, DataWeave buffers use off-heap memory from a pool up to a defined size and allocates the rest using heap memory.`
   If buffers use 60 slots x 1.5 MB in the off-heap space and if the size continues to grow will the additional part move to the heap space and if at all it moves to the heap space when/what is the limit it will be pushed to file storage?

Apparently, the documentation looks quite confusing, appreciate if someone could help in calrifying the confusions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sounds about right. If the size is exceeded, the data can not fit into the memory reserved and has to go to a temporary buffer file.
2. The documentation is incorrect at this time about `com.mulesoft.dw.buffersize` determining if the data should go to a temporary buffer file. I'm sure the documentation will be fixed soon.
3. The decision to move data to a temporary buffer file is not by the number of slots. Rather is if a single slot (of 1.5 MB) can contain the data.

Comment: Thanks for the updating aled, point 2 is clarified. but for point 1 what I am trying to understand is that which value among `com.mulesoft.dw.max_memory_allocation` and `com.mulesoft.dw.buffersize` decides that the file goes to temporary file?

Also for point 3, I understand your point but my question here is that  this statement `and allocates the rest using heap memory.` says it first uses off-heap, once filled up it uses `heap` space, now both are in memory, shouldn't it be just off heap and then write to files?

Comment: `com.mulesoft.dw.max_memory_allocation` is the one that decides to use temporary files when exceeded.

Comment: `com.mulesoft.dw.memory_pool_size` just defines the amount slots in the pool of off-heap memory, if all of them are taken, it starts to use heap memory.
We are fixing this issue in the docs. Thanks